# When does init block of object get called?

Tags: kotlin

I tried to know when the `init` block of `object` gets called in Kotlin using the below code, but I don't get any result in the console:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    TestObj
    TestObj
}

object TestObj {
    var count = 0

    init {
        fun howManyTimes() {
            println(++count)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Dimitri's answer is correct for your problem, however the correct answer for your specific question is:

if it is a `class` instantiation, the `init` is executed before the constructor is called.

if it is an `object`, according to Kotlin documentation, it will be called whenever the (singleton) object is called first time, as static objects are lazy initialized.

Answer (score 3):

You are not getting any output in console, because you are declaring function inside the `init` block, and not calling it.

Change `TestObj` code to:

```
object TestObj {

    var count = 0

    init {
        howManyTimes()
    }

    fun howManyTimes() {
        println(++count)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Above answer gives a clear explanation as to why you are not getting expected output, I would try to answer your question

> When does init block of object get called?

From [kotlin in action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action)

> The init keyword introduces an initializer block. Such blocks contain
>   initialization code that’s executed when the class is created, and are
>   intended to be used together with primary constructors. Because the
>   primary constructor has a constrained syntax, it can’t contain the
>   initialization code; that’s why you have initializer blocks. If you
>   want to, you can declare several initializer blocks in one class.

Comment: That's a good explanation of when a _class_ init block is called; Hasan was asking about when an _object_ init block is called.